# Преобразование типов C++. Динамическая типизация?

Tags: c++

Создаю класс для динамической типизации как высокур. я.п. (Например: Python, JavaScript, PHP)

Ошибка в деструкторе класса box (~box())

Я преобразовал переменную pointer (void *) в const char с помощью reinterpret_cast(pointer);

Я не знаю почему не выводиться значение *value? Если в функции set все нормально!

[image: Ошибка Segmentation fault (core dumped)]

```
#include <cstdio>

class box
{
    void *pointer;

public:

    box() {}

    box(const auto argument)
    {
        set(argument);
    }

    void operator = (const auto argument)
    {
        set(argument);
    }

    void set(const auto argument)
    {
        static auto *value = new auto(argument);
        pointer = value;
        printf("%c\n", argument);
        printf("%p\n", &argument);
        printf("%p\n", value);
        printf("%c\n", *value);
        printf("%p\n", pointer);
    }

    ~box()
    {
        printf("%p\n", pointer);
        const char * value = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(pointer);
        printf("%p\n", value);
        printf("%s\n", *value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    box a;
    a = 'I';

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `std::any` или `boost::any` ?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", *value);` может `%c` всё же? Логично что не смогло вывести строку.

Comment: Спасибо) Да глупая ошибка)

Comment: Тут стоит отметить, что в конструкторе `pointer` остается неинициализированным, может затираться при копировании. А в память, выделенная через new никогда не освобождается.

Answer (score -1):

```
~box()
{
    printf("%p\n", pointer);
    const char * value = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(pointer);
    printf("%p\n", value);
    printf("%s\n", *value);
}
```

Comment: А чем это отличается от того что в вопросе ?